# UIWebview with Swift - change URL from push notification

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

AppDelegate.swift

```
var vc = ViewController()
..

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> void) {
    if let pushUrl = userInfo[AnyHashable("pushUrl")] {
        let pushUrlStr = pushUrl as! String
        vc.changeWebviewURL(url: pushUrlStr)
    }
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
}
```

}

ViewController.swift

```
@IBOutlet weak var webVeiw: UIWebview!
..

func changeWebviewURL(url: String) {
    print("changeWebviewURL : \(url)")
    let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    webView?.loadRequest(request)
}
```

Push Notification is works well and "changeWebViewURL" is definitely called.
But why does not Webview response? URL has not changed.

Comment: in here you get the output `print("changeWebviewURL : \(url)")`

Comment: output is chagneWebviewURL : http://www.google.com

Comment: your url is invalid so that the reason the webview not loaded at the same time are you added the NSTransport Securtity in your .plist